# How to expand search bar after pressing search icon in the header(appbar) | React native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, search, react-animated

As I'm new to react native i dont know how to implement the searchbar in header. Please take a look at the image provided below.

[the search icon in the appbar when clicked should expand on click.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV4TH.png)

[expanded search bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbvG6.png)

I have created an Search icon by using vector icons and I just wanna know how to expand search bar icon when someone presses on it..

<Appbar.Action icon={() => }
onPress={_handleSearch} /> - this is the search icon.

```
//HomeScreen.tsx
import React,{ useEffect }  from 'react';
import { Alert, BackHandler, StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { theme } from '../components/theme';
import { SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {Appbar} from 'react-native-paper';
import SearchComponent from '../components/SearchBar';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

function Notification() {
 return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
     <Text>Notification!</Text>
   </View>
  );
}

function Account(props: any) {
 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Notification!</Text>
  </View>
 );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeScreen = () => {

const _handleSearch = () => {
    <SearchComponent />;
};

return (
<SafeAreaProvider>

 <Appbar.Header>
  <Appbar.Content title="header"  />
  <Appbar.Action icon={() => <AntDesign name="search1" color="white" size={25}/>} 
   onPress={_handleSearch} />
  </Appbar.Header>

   <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
    tabBarStyle: {height: 60},
    headerLeft: ()=> null,
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color}) => {
      let iconName = '';
      if (route.name === 'Home') {
        iconName = focused
          ? 'ios-compass'
          : 'ios-compass-outline';
      } else if (route.name === 'Notification') {
        iconName = focused ? 'file-tray' : 'file-tray-outline';
      }
      else if (route.name === 'Account') {
        iconName = focused ? 'md-person-circle' : 'md-person-circle-outline';
      }
      // You can return any component that you like here!
      return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={30} color={color} />;
    },
    tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.primary,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  })}
  >
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{headerShown:false}} component={UserListView} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Notification" options={{headerShown:false}} component= 
  {Notification}/>
  <Tab.Screen name="Account" options={{headerShown:false}} component={Account} />
</Tab.Navigator>
</SafeAreaProvider>
 );
};

export default HomeScreen;

//SearchBar.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

const SearchComponent = () => {
 const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('');
 const onChangeSearch = (query: React.SetStateAction<string>) => setSearchQuery(query);

 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Searchbar
      style={[styles.Searchbar, styles.elevation]}
      placeholder="Search"
      icon={() => <AntDesign name="search1" color="white" size={25}/>}
      onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
      value={searchQuery} children={undefined} onPressIn={undefined} onPressOut= 
      {undefined} textAlign={undefined} autoComplete={undefined}    />
     </View>
     );
    };

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      Searchbar: {
      marginTop:10,
      width: '100%',
      marginVertical: 10,
      boxShadow: '0px 3px 26px rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.15)',
      backgroundColor:'#FFFF',
      borderRadius:10,
      height:60,
     },
    container: {
      flex:1,
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent:'center',
      marginRight:12,
     },
    elevation: {
     elevation: 20,
     },
   });

export default SearchComponent;
```